# display dropdown options in fastapi without using enum type

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am trying to display options in fastapi auto generated documentation page, I can do for enum types as the documentation suggests here https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#create-an-enum-class.

My code is as follows:

for `main.py` I have:

```
from enum import Enum
from db import engine,SessionLocal
from models import Example,ExampleModel,Base,Color
from fastapi import FastAPI,Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import select

app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.get("/colors",response_model=list[ExampleModel])
def read_colors(color: Color ,db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return db.execute(select(Example).where(Example.colors == color)).scalars().all()
```

For `models.py` I have:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped,mapped_column,DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy import Identity,Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict
import enum

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Color(str,enum.Enum):
    RED = 'RED'
    BLUE = 'BLUE'

class Example(Base):
    __tablename__='example'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Identity(always=True),primary_key=True)
    colors: Mapped[Color] = mapped_column(Enum(Color))

class ExampleModel(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    id: int
    colors: Color
```

This way `Color` renders nicely in the docs page:

[image]

However let's assume my database table would be like this:

```
class Example(Base):
    __tablename__='example'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Identity(always=True),primary_key=True)
    colors: Mapped[str]
```

In this case `colors` is just a text field and contains several different values, maybe 10 to 15 different ones, and these color values may change over time. I would like to dynamically generate a dropdown for the different values of colors as well in this case. Is this possible ?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to have an automatic documentation generation tool to read the values from your database to dynamically include this information in the generated documentation?

Comment: I think you need to commit to have all the possible values of colors in the enum for simplicity. Otherwise, I think you will have to write a configuration file and then you will need to load it the values from that file in a way.

Comment: @Guillius correct

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are "using the tool wrong". Documentation is about the code, not about the data in the database. If the field is a textfield which can have random string data from a user (similar to a field containing the street name of the user's home address), your code cannot contain a list of possibilities from the actual database and therefore your documentation cannot have this (and should not need this) as documentation is based on the code not the data.

In case you want to work around this (but you actually shouldn't do this): code a script that reads the list of possibilities from the database and copy this information to a python file (a file with a python enum definition for example). This file can then be used by the automatic documentation generation tool to include this information in the generated docs.

Do consider the possibility that you want to do something that is not the intention or purpose of a documentation generation tool.